# Is there a unit testing library for asserting dto-domain object "equality" via reflection?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, reflection, poco, dto

I want to automatically assert equality of all matching public get-set properties of a domain entity to it's respective DTO. Like AutoMapper but for comparison.

Ideally it should be a narrowly-focused small library rather than an extra feature of a larger one.

Comment: You may serialize your objects to JSON then compare the resulting strings.

Comment: @Guillaume The number of properties might not necessarily match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something that works:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects

```
public static class AssertEx
{
    public static void PublicGetSetPropertiesAreEqual<TDto, TEntity>(TDto dto, TEntity entity)
    {
        var result = new CompareLogic(new ComparisonConfig{ IgnoreObjectTypes = true }).Compare(dto, entity);

        if (result.AreEqual)
            return;

        throw new AssertFailedException(result.DifferencesString);
    }
}
```